# Is there any knot showing infinitely many crossings?

Tags: knot-theory

Let $K$ be any unknot. Is it possible that $K$ shows infinitely many crossings?

And if it is possible: How to get $K$ from the simplest unknot through Reidemeister moves?

Comment: There is no such thing as a polygon with infinitely many edges.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, thank you for the comment. I have made the question corrected.

Comment: @user50727: Your correction did not clarify anything. What is a polygon with infinitely many edges?

Comment: @studiosus, I am sorry. I intended Question 2 was the corrected version of Question 1.

Comment: Then you should simply remove question 1, if what you mean to ask is question 2. Incidentally, Reidemeister moves are useless if you have infinitely many crossings (one cannot even define them properly).

Comment: I suppose by "polygon having infinitely many edges" you intended something like: A path which, when subdivided at some well-ordered countable collection of points (or perhaps a finite union of such, with minor modifications to the following), is a straight line on the interval from any one to the next.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [wild knots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_knot) with infinitely many crossings. A knot is *wild* if it is not *tame*, where this means that the knot extends to an embedded $S^1 \times D^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^3$. Every tame knot can be realized as a finite polygonal path.

Note that a smooth or PL knot is necessarily tame.

If you take the idea for the construction of the wild knot in the image in that wikipedia article but do it with different crossings you can make it an unknot.

Knot diagrams for equivalent tame knots have a finite sequence of Reidemeister moves  relating them. This doesn't work for wild knots.

---

A famous use of wild knots is the [Mazur swindle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Mazur_swindle).