# Knots with infinite crossing

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

For me knots are embedding of $S^1$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

I have following questions:

- Will knots have infinite crossing?
- If so, Why are we considering only knots with finite crossing ?

Can someone elaborate aes answer on the question :[Is there any knot showing infinitely many crossings?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1091430/is-there-any-knot-showing-infinitely-many-crossings)

Comment: Can you be more specific on what isn't clear to you in aes answer to the question you referenced?

Comment: Thank you. I did not get why every tame knot can be realized as a finite polygonal path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As answered in the topic you linked, there are knots with infinite many crossings in a diagram. For example wild knots, and some people consider them. The reason the finite case is much more popular is that any smooth knot has a diagram with finite number of crossings, and any diagram has all information about a knot.

Comment: Thank you. But, Why any smooth knot have finite number of crossing? and also what do you mean by smooth? did you mean by $C^{\infty}$?

Comment: The smooth $C^{\infty}$ and the polygonal knots are the same (in this dimension). The proof of finiteness is in R.H. Crowell and R.H. Fox, Introduction to knot theory, Springer-Verlag (1963). Shortly, when your projection induces infinitely many crossing, just rotate a knot in the three-space "a little" and the new projection will have finitely many crossings.